# CvSVM was not declared in this scope Error

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I am using OpenCV 3.0.0

I have included all these libraries and namespaces,but I still get the error of "CvSVM is not declared in this scope"

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/ml.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::ml;
using namespace std;
```

When I run this code:

```
CvSVM svm;
```

I get the error.

Comment: Where is CvSVM defined?  Which header?  And in what namespace?

Comment: use `Ptr<SVM> svm = SVM::create();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In OpenCV 3.0 `CvSVM` has been renamed to `SVM` and moved to namespace `cv::ml` (actually also in previous version `SVM` was a typedef for `CvSVM`).

Since `SVM` is an abstract class, you can't instantiate it. You need to call `SVM::create()`.

So you need to do:

```
cv::Ptr<cv::ml::SVM> svm = cv::ml::SVM::create();
```

or simply:

```
using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::ml;
...
Ptr<SVM> svm = SVM::create();
```

You don't need `CvSVMParams`anymore. Simply set the parameters directly to the `svm`:

```
Ptr<SVM> svm = SVM::create();
svm->setType(SVM::C_SVC);
svm->setKernel(SVM::RBF);
// etc
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. And what should I use for CvSVMParams?

Comment: see updated answer. You can look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33319975/5008845) for a (quite complex) sample, or [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/ml/introduction_to_svm/introduction_to_svm.html) from OpenCV tutorials