# how to create matrix from integer response of for loop in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, for-loop, matrix

I am working on SVM implementation in opencv. I got predict result as 0,1,2,3,4. I assign these value to integer variable response. I choose image size (512 * 512). I want to create matrix of (512*512) of that value and display as image. I am using MS visual studio. My code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; ++i)

for (int j = 0; j < image.cols; ++j)
{

    Mat sampleMat = (Mat_<float>(1, 2) << j,i);
    int response = svm->predict(sampleMat);

    //cout<<"labels : "<< endl ;
    //cout<<"("<< i <<","<< j << ") :" << response <<endl;



    image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)= colors_region[(int)response];  

}
```

Comment: Does `colors_region` stores `cv::Vec3b`s? If yes, you should only give the value `colors_region[(int)response]` to `image`, i.e.: `image = colors_region[(int)response]` (suppose that `image` has been allocated before).

Comment: i use this code for color region :                                                   vector<Vec3b> colors_region;
  vector<Vec3b> colors_data;

Comment: @kornel I got image as output with your suggestion.                              But, without using color_region , is it possible to store value of (int response ) in array or matrix to display as image ?

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33319975/5008845)?

Comment: @Miki No, but it will be helpful. I got image output with Kornel's suggetion.

Comment: If i change from 2 to 3 in  Mat sampleMat = (Mat_<float>(1, 2) << j,i); i got error: opencv error assertion failed ( this -> it == (const Mat_<_Tp>*)this->it.m)->end()) in cv:: MatCommaInitializer. I use three text file for input data and for that i choose three column(j=3). Give me idea to solve it.